# C++ What are the differences between Microsoft's ComPtr and c++ unique_ptr, shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm seeing cases of these pointer classes mixed in together in these projects.

Sometimes they use std:unique_ptr, shared_ptr, and sometimes I see Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr.

Just wondering what the differences are and how do I know which to use?

Comment: I suggest you always use `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` as then your software will be far more portable between platforms and may depend on less external libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` signifies a **unique** pointer to an object, such that you can not copy the pointer; but you may still move the pointer.

e.g.

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<float>(5.0f);
std::unique_ptr other_ptr = ptr;
```

will not compile, but

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<float>(5.0f);
std::unique_ptr other_ptr = std::move(ptr);
```

will.

---

`std::shared_ptr` signifies a pointer to an object that multiple other `shared_ptr`s may point to. It is copyable and movable.

The reason you would not use `shared_ptr` over `unique_ptr` all the time is that `shared_ptr` will be slower upon construction and deconstruction and any time you need to pass it into a function, you may incur this slow (de)construction.

as an example

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<float>(5.0f);
std::shared_ptr other_ptr = ptr;
```

is (maybe a lot) slower than moving the original pointer into the new one because the compiler has to keep track of how many `shared_ptr` instances point to the object so that when a `shared_ptr` is de-constructed if it is the last pointer to that object it will delete it.

---

As for `ComPtr`... please don't use it unless **absolutely** necessary. Which is almost never. The reason why you probably see it used within the project you refer to is that some Microsoft specific APIs use it, which is one of those times where you do have to use it.

---

### EDIT

To show the advantages and/or disadvantages of these different smart pointers, and when you should be choosing them, a decent example program is really necessary. So here you go!

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<float> p){}
void f(std::shared_ptr<float> p){}

void g(std::unique_ptr<float> &p){}
void g(std::shared_ptr<float> &p){}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    auto uptr = std::make_unique<float>(6.9f);
    auto sptr = std::make_shared<float>(4.20f);

    // f(uptr);
    // error, trying to make a copy of a unique_ptr

    f(sptr);
    // fine, shared_ptr may be copied

    f(std::make_unique<float>(6.9f));
    f(std::make_shared<float>(4.20f));
    // both fine, value initialized in function call and moved into function.

    g(uptr);
    g(sptr);
    // both fine, shared and unique pointers may be passed by reference
    // as no copy or move is made.
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so does that mean that I can't have a unique_ptr as a function argument?

Comment: No, but kind of. It means you can't have a `unique_ptr` passed into a function by **value**.
so `void f(unique_ptr p)` would not compile if you passed an existing `unique_ptr` but any type of reference or pointer would work fine.

Comment: You _can_ have a unique_ptr value parameter to a function, it just requires the caller to pass in a value unique pointer (returned from another function or constructed in the call) or std::move an existing unique_ptr. It can be a good pattern for a function expecting to take ownership of an object.